# my images will not loaded properly in my images folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am writing an web crawler that will extract title description and images from url ..i want to save images in images folder in my project that is save correctly but images does not loaded completely its shown an fatal error :fatal error reading PNG image file: not a png file...i am set an buffer to store the image that will extended its byte but still the same error .all of the images are 1.7 kb that is not happen means my images will not loaded properly
Any help will be appreciable :
here is a code  :

```
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var title = $('head title').text();
    var keywords = $('head meta[name=keywords]').attr('content');
    var desc = $('head meta[name=description]').attr('content');
    var links = $('a');
    var imgArray = [];

    $('img').each(function(){
   var temp = $(this).attr("src");
    imgArray.push(temp);
    var downloadImage = function (temp, fileName) {
    http.get(temp, function (res) {
          var imagedata = ''
          res.setEncoding('binary');
          res.on('data', function(chunk){
          imagedata +=  chunk;
          });

         res.on('end', function(){
         var imgArr = temp.split("/");
         var Name = util.id();
          fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/img/' + Name + ".png" , imagedata, 'binary', function(err)
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('image saved')
            });
            });
            });
           };
        downloadImage(temp,'test.png');
        console.log("image is  " + imgArray);
        });
       console.log('Crawling "%s" | %s',title,this.url);
```

Comment: Sorry, for yet asking another question in return, but I am not acquainted with node.js. What does `var $ = cheerio.load(html);` do? Who or what is `cheerio`?

Comment: its an npm package that will load the html page and then extract the data from it...

Comment: Have you tried looking at your saved 'image' files? Very likely they will contain some text message which you can open in a text editor if you change the extension to `.txt`. This text message might give you some clue as to why the image itself was not found.

Comment: I think you want var request = http.get(temp,function(res){..}). You are currently trying to pass an array to http.get, not a url

Comment: @nfreeze yes i am also try with temp the problem is same images are save but it does not open due to unloaded error

Comment: Let node do the work by piping the response directly into a fs stream: `http.get(temp,function(res)res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("myimage.png"));});`

Comment: no this will not work ...nfreeze i update my code this will return some of the images properly loaded but still there are few images that will not loaded yet